# Get Domain name from current page and compare with a list of domain using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to use a html template for some custom domain, it will redirect to a custom domain if is using to a different domain.

Example:

```
http://domain.com/something.html
```

I will get

```
http://domain.com
```

and compare it with my list domain

```
http://qwe.com
http://bcd.com
```

if not redirect current page to efg.com

Comment: use `window.location.hostname`

Comment: Thank for your response! Can you check my http://jsfiddle.net/8q5kq/1/

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AP8nc/1/ - the fiddle is not working because of a same origin policy issue...

Comment: `$.inArray()` returns `-1` if the item is not found.... so you need to alter you if statement to `$.inArray(x, whiteList) == -1`, also use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
//1.grap using
domain=window.location.hostname
//2. compare
//TODO :code to compare
```

for more info, visit [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp)